# Reinitialize Transactional replication which is 5 months behind

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have given new server recently and found one of of the publication - subscription is out of sync and Distributer agent stopped as well. After checking with the team, looks like they wanted this and asking me to reestablish it.

Overview: It is using Transactional replication which is 5 months behind and 3600 tables are replicated and no other objects (like SP, Fn), All 3600 table size is roughly 225 GB. The database in subscriber is having lot of non replicated tables. I cannot use backup reinitialize.

The error in the error log is been 6 month old. I have tried to reinitialize the subscription but it is not working, it is sending some more error in the replication monitor.

***Error in the replication monitor after reinitialize***:

Procedure or function sp_MSupd_dboXXX has too many arguments specified.

The row was not found at the Subscriber when applying the replicated (null) command for Table '(null)' with Primary Key(s): (null)

***Error from log***:
2023-05-17 04:23:09.660 spid120
Replication-Replication Distribution Subsystem: agent XXXX_name failed. The subscription(s) have been marked inactive and must be reinitialized.
NoSync subscriptions will need to be dropped and recreated.

Any suggestion how to make this work again.

Comment: It sounds like you will need to rebuild it from scratch - a complete reinitialization.

Comment: Thank you that is what I have planned.